# disabling sound in a game increases FPS

Tags: cpu, gpu, fps

Take League of Legends for example.. When I have my sound on I get an average of 50 FPS, but when I disable it my FPS rises to 60.
Why Is this?  I thought sounds were played using the CPU and FPS is dependant on your GPU right?  What do these things have in common? It's not like sound has to be rendered or something, right?

Comment: How many "cores" do you have?  sounds in these systems are processed (some say a lot) in these new systems, using very good methods. Much of the processing is now done in the cpu (fpu), even with supporting hardware like special hardware audio cards. Add to that there are 3D processes of 3D games where 5.1 and 7.1 type of sounds are processed to provide the dimentional sounds, are they behind you or in front.  Rendered ? sort of :-)

Comment: Is this on-board sound?

Answer (score 1):

On a modern PC, GPU is almost never a bottleneck. There are lot of things that need to be done on CPU in every frame: physics simulation, AI calculations, applying any game mechanics. Rendering the scene on GPU is only the last step in main game loop. So it follows that freeing up some CPU time makes the game run faster.

However, I would be very surprised if overhead related to sound would amount to 33% increase in speed, I would suspect something else is in play here.

Comment: An increase from 50 to 60 is 20%. ;) EDIT: Noticed you answered before OP edited the question.